# How can I add to a registry key

Tags: powershell, windows-registry

I need to create a script to run on a server that I do not have access to.

I need the script to append a string to an existing string value (Type = REG_SZ).  The script cannot just replace the entire string with a new value as I don't know what is currently in the entry and I can't lose what is already there.

I was thinking along the lines of regini.exe, but i couldn't figure out how to export, append, import with regini.exe and a batch file.  Maybe powershell could do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powershell is a solid bet here.

```
$AppendValue="\Homes"
$RegRoot=Get-ItemProperty "hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion"
$RegValue=$RegRoot.CommonFilesDir+$AppendValue
Set-ItemProperty -path HKLM:\software\microsoft\windows\Currentversion -Name CommonFilesDir -Value $RegValue
```

Windows gets twitchy about anything that touches reg or registry.exe, where scripts like the above can run with less complaining.

Comment: +1 So much cleaner than my answer, which I was forced to delete. :)

Comment: Your second registry path doesn't match your first, so this script is creating a new value with the appended string, but I get the gist.

That's slick!

Comment: @Mark Arnott That's what I get for doing it off the top of my head. Glad it worked out! Powershell is very, very nifty.

Answer (score 1):

Vbscript will do this too

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim Temp
'For the purpose of demonstration create a new key and give it a default of 1
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\MyNewKey\", 1 ,"REG_SZ"
'Add a value 
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\MyNewKey\MyValue", "Hello world!"
'read the value we just wrote append more text to it and write it back
Temp = WshShell.RegRead("HKCU\MyNewKey\MyValue")
Temp = Temp & " More Text"
WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\MyNewKey\MyValue",Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using PowerShell, or using Windows' REG.EXE, e.g.:

```
@echo off  
setlocal

set SERVER=myserver  
set KEY=HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run  
set VALUE=myvalue  
set APPEND_DATA=my appended text

REM *** GET THE EXISTING VALUE  
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%V in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "\\%SERVER%\%KEY%" /v "%VALUE%"') do set DATA=%%W

REM *** SET THE VALUE  
set DATA=%DATA:"=\"%  
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe add "\\%SERVER%\%KEY%" /v "%VALUE%" /t REG_SZ /f /d "%DATA%%APPEND_DATA%"  

endlocal
```

Comment: In [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), which SF (partially) uses for formatting, four space characters, rather than back ticks, allows for multi-line code formatting.